# logo image not sending by mail in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to send image also with mail but not attachment I want to send like an invitation or request with company logo like a card

following is my code

```
Sub SenMail()
    Dim mail2 As MailMessage = New MailMessage()
    mail2.From = New MailAddress("erpnoreplyy@gmail.com")
    mail2.To.Add("shahbaz1604a@aptechgdn.net")
    mail2.Subject = "test email"
    'text/html
    'Dim plainview As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("this is my text", Nothing, "plain/html")
    'Dim htmlview As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("Here is an embedded image.<img src=cid:companylogo>", Nothing, "text/html")
    Dim logo As LinkedResource = New LinkedResource("f:\\logindreuss.gif", MediaTypeNames.Image.Gif)
    logo.ContentId = "MyImage"
    'logo.ContentId = "logo"
    Dim body As String = "" &
        "<img src=cid:MyImage  width='100px' height='100px' alt='logostring'>"
    '"<img src='" & htmlview.ToString() & "' alt='htmlstring'>" &
    '"<img src='" & plainview.ToString() & "'  alt='plainstring'>"
    mail2.IsBodyHtml = True
    mail2.Body = body
    'htmlview.LinkedResources.Add(logo)
    'mail2.AlternateViews.Add(plainview)
    'mail2.AlternateViews.Add(htmlview)
    'Dim smtp As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("465.0.0")
    Dim av As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, Nothing, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)
    av.LinkedResources.Add(logo)
    Dim smtp As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient()
    smtp.Port = 587
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("erpnoreplyy@gmail.com", "naeem1234")
    smtp.EnableSsl = True
    smtp.Send(mail2)
End Sub
```

Comment: And what's your question?  Are you hitting exceptions or unintended behavior.  You've told us what you want to do, but not what isn't working

Comment: You can provide link of your image in img tag of html if you don't want show your image link then you can convert image to byte array and pass to body as I mention in answer

Comment: email was sending successfully every time just in src wasn't getting by image tag, by the i have solved this with alterative views

Answer (score 0):

Here you can convert your image to byte and pass it to mail body as html, If Image is still not showing then you have to decode that Base64String online and you get simple URI and put in your img tag of body

```
 Dim b_logo = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\Users\yogesh\Pictures\sclhneider.png")

            Dim body As String = "<img src='data:image/png;base64," & Convert.ToBase64String(b_logo) & "' />"
```